# How to verify lipschitz function of variables are sub-gaussian variables?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, concentration-of-measure

Suppose $X$ is a sub-Gaussian random variable with parameter $\sigma > 0$. Let $f(x)$ be a Lipschitz function with Lipschitz constant $L$. It is said that $f(X)$ should be also a sub-Gaussian with parameter of form $cL\sigma$ where $c$ is a constant.

I thought we should first utilize the definition of sub-Gauss dist $\mathbb{P}(|X-\mu|>t)\leq 2\exp(-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2})$.
Denote mean of $f(X)$ as $f(\mu')$, then
$$\mathbb{P}(|f(X) - f(\mu')|>t) \leq \mathbb{P}(L|X-\mu'|>t)\\
\leq \mathbb{P}(L|X-\mu'| + L|\mu-\mu'|>t) \\
= \mathbb{P}(L|X-\mu'|>t - L|\mu-\mu'|) \\
\leq 2\exp (-\frac{(t-L|\mu-mu'|)^2}{2\sigma^2L^2})\\
\leq 2\exp (-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2L^2}+\frac{|\mu-mu'|^2}{2\sigma^2})$$
So how to continue with the later term in RHS i.e. $\frac{|\mu-mu'|^2}{2\sigma^2}$ to get  the form $cL\sigma$?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the inequality using variable substitution of $E(f(X))$.

Let $Y$ be an i.i.d random variable of $X$. By equivalence of definition of sub-Gaussian, $\exists \sigma>0$ s.t. $\mathbb{E}(e^{\frac{X^2}{\sigma^2}})\leq e$.

$$
\mathbb{E}(\exp{\frac{(f(X)-\mathbb{E}(f(X)))^2}{c^2}}) = \mathbb{E}(\exp{\frac{(f(X)-\mathbb{E}(f(Y)))^2}{(cL\sigma)^2}})\\
= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{P}(X=x)\exp{\frac{(f(x)-\mathbb{E}(f(Y)))^2}{(cL\sigma)^2}}dx\\
\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{P}(X=x)\mathbb{E}\exp{\frac{(f(x)-f(Y))^2}{(cL\sigma)^2}}dx\\
= \mathbb{E}\exp\frac{(f(X)-f(Y))^2}{(cL\sigma)^2}\\
\leq \mathbb{E}\exp\frac{L^2(X-Y)^2}{(cL\sigma)^2}\\
\leq \mathbb{E}\exp\frac{2L^2X^2+2L^2Y^2}{(cL\sigma)^2}\\
= \mathbb{E}\exp\frac{4X^2}{c^2\sigma^2} \leq e\\
$$

Therefore when $c\geq2$, $f(X)$ is sub-Gaussian w.r.t. $cL\sigma$.